# ImageCache swift 3

Tags: ios, json, image, caching, swift3

Hi i want to cache my images coming from json. I have made a networkService which downloads and parse the json  and i use the func downloadImage() which makes http request of the imageurl.Then I update my episode with this func but images are still downloading on scroll

```
    var episode: Product! {   
        didSet {

            self.updateUI()
        }
    }



let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

    func updateUI()
    {
        menuItemNameLabel?.text = episode.title
        ingredientsItemLabel?.text = episode.summary
        priceItemLabel?.text = episode.price
        menuItemImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Koulourades")

        if let thumbnailURL = episode.thumbnailURL {
            let networkService = NetworkService(url: thumbnailURL)
            networkService.downloadImage({ (imageData) in


                if let imageFromCache = self.imageCache.object(forKey: self.episode.thumbnailURL as AnyObject) as? UIImage {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                         self.menuItemImageView?.image = imageFromCache
                         return
                    })
                }


               DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                    self.imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: self.episode.thumbnailURL as AnyObject)

                    self.menuItemImageView?.image = imageToCache
                })


            })
        }
    }//--end updateUI()
```

Comment: Thats good for what you have done, but what is the issue???

Comment: The issue is that everytime i scroll i wait the images to be downloaded ! I want to be downloaded one time only

Comment: Use this -> https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you need to resolve your problem is called Lazy Loading in which application will download the images at once and cache it into the memory.

There are multiple third party libraries available for caching images.

Libraries like ,

1) HanekeSwift ->  https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

2) Kingfisher -> https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

3) SDWebImage -> https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

4) AlamofireImage  -> https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage